# If/Else Statement Console Logging But Else Block Breaking Code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm experiencing a strange issue with my `If` statement.

I'm changing the state (true/false) of an object based on `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`.

I am able to run the code when it's true, however on the `else` statement, if I input any code, it breaks. Although I am able to console log within else block.

Here's [the codepen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/wvwGjVG)

Comment: the error states `document.querySelector` is null - so clearly that code is running before there's anything but the single div in the page

Comment: The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches. If no matches are found, null is returned. Is it returning null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to loop in the node-list and apply the style

   ```
    if (isHovered === true) {
    console.log("hovered");

    var a = document.querySelectorAll(".nav .subnav-block li a");

    console.log(a);

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].style.color = "green";
    }
   // document.querySelector('.nav .subnav-block li a ').style.color = 'green';
   } else {
   console.log("exited");
   // below code will break if uncommented

   var a = document.querySelectorAll(".nav .subnav-block li a");

   console.log(a);

   for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].style.color = "white";
   }

   // document.querySelectorAll('.nav .subnav-block li a').style.color = "white";
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks - Question: why do we need to loop through node-list. Why can't we just simply set color using `a.style.color = "green";` ?

Comment: Hey Eric, yea this can something get confusing. Just like a regular array, you can't make all the items green only by setting it to green.  Instead, you must loop through each item and change its characteristic. Likewise, querySelectorAll returns a node list which needs to be looped through each a tag to apply all style.

Answer (score 0):

Null check your query selector

The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

```
let element = document.querySelector('.nav .subnav-block li a ');

if(element)
element.style.color = 'white';
```

Comment: You need to add in an if statement to check if the element is null, before setting the style.